# Wrong display of horizontal layout inside ASCellNode

Tags: ios, swift, asyncdisplaykit

I have this code written using AsyncDisplayKit:

```
override open func layoutSpecThatFits(_ constrainedSize: ASSizeRange) -> ASLayoutSpec {

    let horizonTitleDate = ASStackLayoutSpec(direction: .horizontal, spacing: 5, justifyContent: .start, alignItems: ASStackLayoutAlignItems.start, children: [title,space, datetime])
    let verticalMess = ASStackLayoutSpec(direction: .vertical, spacing: 5, justifyContent: .start, alignItems: ASStackLayoutAlignItems.start, children: [horizonTitleDate, desc])
    let horizonMess = ASStackLayoutSpec(direction: .horizontal, spacing: 5, justifyContent: .start, alignItems: ASStackLayoutAlignItems.start, children: [avatar, verticalMess])


    //desc.style.width = ASDimensionMake(constrainedSize.max.width - 100)
    desc.style.alignSelf                 = .stretch
    desc.style.flexGrow                  = 1.0
    desc.style.flexShrink                  = 1.0
    verticalMess.style.alignSelf         = .stretch
    verticalMess.style.flexGrow          = 1.0
    horizonTitleDate.style.alignSelf     = .stretch
    let insets  = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)
    return ASInsetLayoutSpec(insets: insets, child: horizonMess)

}
```

I obtain this:

[image]

As you can see, the yellow TextNode, is larger then cellNode, and do not become 2 lines, in portrait mode look like this:

[image]

If I draw only vertical layout without avatar, I obtain correct view:

[image]

What's wrong? thanks!

Comment: have you tried to use `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` ?

Comment: yes, it's the same!

Comment: when you say its the same you mean that it works o its wrong again? xd

Comment: wrong again! sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see `flexShrink` for `verticalMess`. Try just add this line:

```
    verticalMess.style.flexShrink                  = 1.0
```